# Handle application_start without global.asax

Tags: global-asax

Is there a way to handle the `application_start` "event" without using the global.asax?

The best I can come up with is an HttpModule that checks some static variable on every `begin_request`, which is INCREDIBLY wasteful :(

Do I have any other options?

Thanks

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want rid of the very badly designed, reflection invoked global.asax methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the reflection-based "pseudo-events" in Global.asax are not accessible in any other way than by reflection. However, for the application_start event, you might be able to achieve similar functionality by overriding the Init() method on a subclass of HttpApplication. Some functionality might not be accessible, as it probably fires on a slightly different point in the lifecycle.

Alternatively, if you're going with an HttpModule, couldn't you just use the Init() method instead of begin_request?

Comment: no because there are a pool of HttpModules, they arent instantiated as singletons, each requests could in theory get a new instance.

Comment: admittedly this approach would be less wasteful than begin_request, but its still, not ideal

Answer (score 0):

If your code is existing in the website, you can use the largely undocumented 'AppInitialize' method.  Add this static method to any class in your *web* project.

(Note: it will not work if contained in a compiled assembly within the site.)

For more info, search for "AppInitialize".  (Ex: http://www.bing.com/search?q=appinitialize+msdn&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE9bSRC)